# Задача о рюкзаке с использованием bitset

Tags: c++, алгоритм, динамическое-программирование

Недавно узнал, что для ускорения решения задачи о рюкзаке можно применить битовое сжатие с использованием структуры bitset в C++. Есть задача: Существует ***N*** предметов с весами ***w***. Надо проверить, можно ли выбрать какое-то количество предметов: суммарный вес которых равен ***Weight***.
Вроде бы ничего трудного, но проблема в ограничениях: ***N <= 2500*** и ***Weight <= 6250000***. Увы я не особо понимаю как работает *bitset* в C++, поэтому не могу реализовать решение с такими ограничениями. Нашёл решение в интернете буквально такой же задачи, но понять почему оно не работает у меня не получилось:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <bitset>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;
 
int main() {
    int N, W;
    cin >> N >> W;
    vector<int> w(N);
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        cin >> w[i];
    }
    //vector<bool> A(W + 1);
    bitset<6250001> A;
    A[0] = true;
    for (int i = 1; i <= N; i++) {
        for (int j = W; j >= 0; j--) {
            if (j >= w[i - 1]) {
                A[j] = A[j] | (A[j] << w[i - 1]);
            }
        }
    }
    if (A[W]) {
        cout << "YES";
    } else {
        cout << "NO";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Если вдруг кто уже делал подобную реализацию подскажите, пожалуйста, что мне лучше сделать.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вероятно, неверно переписали код. Должно быть после ИЛИ `(A[j - w[i]])`, что означает, что вес `j` можно составить из веса `w[i]` и `j - w[i]`, если последний существует (возможен).

Кроме того, я изменил нумерацию по `i` на нормальную (на работу это не влияет, просто нелепо)

```
 for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        for (int j = W; j >= w[i]; j--) {
                A[j] = A[j] | A[j - w[i]];
        }
    }
```

Comment: Спасибо большое за исправление! Но у меня есть чувство, что с подобными ограничениями программа за 2 секунду сработать не сможет...

Comment: 15 миллиардов операций, код не распараллеливаемый - да, вряд ли. Однако с битсетом нужно проверять все элементы. А вот если использовать какой-то set, в котором будут храниться только ненулевые элементы - шанс может быть (хотя при наборе весов вроде 1,2,4,8...2^21 set будет тоже плотно заполнен)